# What is the tunnel Darth Maul fell in to?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In *Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace*, Obi Wan fights with Darth Maul on the planet Naboo in Queen Amidala's castle and kills Darth Maul. After his death, Darth Maul fell down a shaft. What is the tunnel called?

[image: A Long Way Down]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42641/discussion-on-question-by-ransara009-what-is-the-tunnel-name-darth-maul-fell-in).

Comment: It's a villain disposal pipe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While fans typically refer to it as a "reactor shaft", more official materials refer to it differently.

According to [the script for the movie *Star Wars Episode 1: The Phantom Menace*](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html), where this event takes place, it is the melting pit connected to the power generator.

> INT. THEED - **POWER GENERATOR - MELTING PIT**
>   
>   OBI-WAN screams as the pulsing electron gate opens, and the SITH LORD
>   attacks him. The DARK LORD is relentless in his assault on the young JEDI.
>   OBI-WAN and DARTH MAUL use the Force to fling objects at each other as they
>   fight. DARTH MAUL seems to have the upper hand as OBI-WAN grows weary.
>   DARTH MAUL catches OBI-WAN off guard, **and the JEDI slips into a melting
>   pit.** He is barely able to hold onto a nozzle on the side of the pit. DARTH
>   MAUL grin evilly at OBI-WAN as he kicks OBI-WAN's lightsaber down the
>   endless shaft.
>   The SITH LORD smiles as he goes in for the kill. At the last moment,
>   OBI-WAN jumps up out of the pit, calls QUI-GON's lightsaber to hi, throwing
>   DARTH MAUL off. **The young JEDI swings with a vengeance, cutting the SITH
>   down. DARTH MAUL falls into the melting pit to his death.**
>   OBI-WAN rushes over to QUI-GON, who is dying.

StarWars.com also calls it a "melting pit" in its page for [the Reactor Core Duel](http://www.starwars.com/video/reactor-core-duel).

> On Naboo, Qui-Gon and Obi-Wan team up to defeat Darth Maul in a lightsaber duel. After cutting Qui-Gon down, Maul faces off with Obi-Wan, who defeats the Sith Lord by **sending his bisected body into a deep melting pit.**

Comment: I've edited the name of the script in for you. I thought linking to it would have been enough.

Comment: As a note, everyone else just calls it a ***Reactor Shaft***. But Starwars.com does call it a melting pit at least on one summary.